# Implement the function foldr using foldl in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

`foldr` (fold-right) basically is the recursive computation is performed in right-to-left order of the values stored in the list. And `foldl` is the reverse of `foldr`. I'm wondering that could people implement the function `foldr` using `foldl`? Any idea is appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering that could people implement the function `foldr` using `foldl` ...

`foldl` traverses the list once from left-to-right – and it's tail-recursive too

```
(define (foldl f acc xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      acc
      (foldl f
             (f acc (car xs))
             (cdr xs))))
```

`foldr` traverses the list once, stacking up the calls to `f` until the last element of the list – it's not tail recursive

```
(define (foldr f acc xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      acc
      (f (foldr f acc (cdr xs))
         (car xs))))
```

We verify their output below –

```
(foldl list 'init '(a b c))
;; '(((init a) b) c)

(foldr list 'init '(a b c))
;; '(((init c) b) a)
```

So sure, you *could* implement `foldr` using `reverse` and `foldl`, but that will traverse the input list twice. The reason each fold exists is so that you can process a list in either direction without traversing it more than once...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Simply reverse the input-list before you pass all arguments to `foldl`:

```
(define (myfoldr func init-val lst)
  (foldl func init-val (reverse lst)))
```

**Test it**

First:

```
(foldr (lambda (el acc) (list el acc))
       '()
       '(1 2 3 4 5))

;; => '(1 (2 (3 (4 (5 ())))))

(foldl (lambda (el acc) (list el acc))
       '()
       '(1 2 3 4 5))

;; => '(5 (4 (3 (2 (1 ())))))
```

And now:

```
(myfoldr (lambda (el acc) (list el acc))
         '()
         '(1 2 3 4 5))

;; => '(1 (2 (3 (4 (5 ())))))
```

**`foldl` by `foldr`**

```
(define (myfoldl func initial-val lst)
  (foldr func init-val (reverse lst)))
```

The test:

```
(myfoldl (lambda (el acc) (list el acc))
         '()
         '(1 2 3 4 5))

;; => '(5 (4 (3 (2 (1 ())))))
```

Comment: Btw `(reverse lst)` is `(foldl cons '() lst)`